# "variable" cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am trying to follow a tutorial in creating an xmpp chat. 
However, it kept showing "R cannot be resolved to a variable". After I inserted import.android.R, the error moved to all variables. SAying that all variables cannot be resolved to a variable.

Here is the code:

```
package com.demo.xmppchat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.R;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class XMPPChatDemoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
    public static final int PORT = 5222;
    public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";
    public static final String USERNAME = "elvira.novellia@gmail.com";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "xxx";

    private XMPPConnection connection;
    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private EditText recipient;
    private EditText textMessage;
    private ListView listview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        recipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.toET);
        textMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.chatET);
        listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        setListAdapter();

        // Set a listener to send a chat text message
        Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String to = recipient.getText().toString();
                String text = textMessage.getText().toString();

                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Sending text " + text + " to " + to);
                Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(text);              
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.sendPacket(msg);
                    messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
                    messages.add(text);
                    setListAdapter();
                }
            }
        });

        connect();
    }

    /**
     * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with the XMPP
     * server
     * 
     * @param connection
     */
    public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                                .getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved " + message.getBody()
                                + " from " + fromName );
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }

    private void setListAdapter() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listitem, messages);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void connect() {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                "Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create a connection
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                        HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
                XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

                try {
                    connection.connect();
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                            + connection.getHost());
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }
                try {
                    // SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
                    connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                    // Set the status to available
                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    connection.sendPacket(presence);
                    setConnection(connection);

                    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "--------------------------------------");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "User: " + entry.getUser());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Name: " + entry.getName());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Type: " + entry.getType());
                        Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                                .getUser());

                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "
                                + entryPresence.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "
                                + entryPresence.getType());
                        Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                        if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "
                                + entryPresence);

                    }
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                            + USERNAME);
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

And here is the error list:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
toET cannot be resolved or is not a field   XMPPChatDemoActivity.java   /XMPPChatDemo/src/com/demo/xmppchat line 54 Java Problem
main cannot be resolved or is not a field   XMPPChatDemoActivity.java   /XMPPChatDemo/src/com/demo/xmppchat line 52 Java Problem
chatET cannot be resolved or is not a field XMPPChatDemoActivity.java   /XMPPChatDemo/src/com/demo/xmppchat line 55 Java Problem
listMessages cannot be resolved or is not a field   XMPPChatDemoActivity.java   /XMPPChatDemo/src/com/demo/xmppchat line 56 Java Problem
sendBtn cannot be resolved or is not a field    XMPPChatDemoActivity.java   /XMPPChatDemo/src/com/demo/xmppchat line 60 Java Problem
listitem cannot be resolved or is not a field   XMPPChatDemoActivity.java   /XMPPChatDemo/src/com/demo/xmppchat line 117    Java Problem
```

I have tried Project -> Clean, but its still not working.

Comment: I think you import the wrong file. Try to remove `import android.R;` and add `import com.demo.xmppchat.R;`

Comment: Remove import android.R;

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the import

```
import android.R;
```

There is no need for the below import unless its in a different package in which case you  use import packagename.R;

```
import com.demo.xmppchat.R;
```

Comment: @user2683347 use `import com.demo.xmppchat.R;`

Comment: Its not working.. the import line is error saying its not resolved.

Comment: **"use import com.demo.xmppchat.R;"** There should never be a need to import the R.java class unless the it's in a different package. It will be done implicitly otherwise.

Comment: @user2683347 what do you see under gen folder.

Comment: @Squonk totally agree

Comment: @user2683347 then you have to check whether there is any error's in resource folder.

Comment: @Raghunandan the error is still the same. if i change it to import.com.demo.xmppchat.R, the error is the same, plus the error in this import line itself..

Comment: @user2683347 it sounds like R.java is not generated. Possibly bcoz of errors in resource files. Fix them and clean and build.

Comment: erros in your resources can bloc the generation of R.java. You have to check the console's log, it shows usually the errors in resources.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this import

```
import android.R;
```

and just press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**O**</kbd>

It will ask for the import if any create conflicts

if it ask for **android.R;** and **com.demo.xmppchat.R;**.

Then chose **com.demo.xmppchat.R**